# How to rounded corners for ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, listviewitem

I am trying to have rounded corners for the highlight and selected background of the ListViewItem

I have the following code:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#F7D073" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#F1A62F" Offset="1"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#F7D073" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#F1A62F" Offset="1"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MouseOverBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#E4F0FD" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#D7EAFD" Offset="1"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=NGGDataForeground, ElementName=NGG}" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MouseOverBrush}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="2"/>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
<ListView x:Name="lstData" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=NGG}" 
          Height="{Binding Path=GridHight, ElementName=NGG}" 
          Width="{Binding Path=GridWidth, ElementName=NGG}" 
          BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent">
</ListView>
```

However for some reason this only rounds the left side and not the right looking for help on how to round all 4 corners.

Comment: If only the left side is getting the rounded corners... then the problem is likely that your ListViewItems (and their rounded borders) are wider than your ListView container. Seeing how you're binding things to an element named NGG... I think you might need to provide more xaml in to see exactly why your ListViewItems are too wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I use the above XAML on a new Window, it works fine for me:

[image]

Could it be possible that the right side of your ListView is not displayed as expected? Maybe the bound GridWidth is a little bit bigger than the control on which it is placed.

Comment: You are absolutely correct (my GridWidth property was too big)

Answer (score 0):

my columns are created dynamically in the code behind

```
public void PopulateGrid(DataSet ds) {
        lstData.View = CreateGridViewColumns(ds.Tables[0]);
        lstData.ItemsSource = ((IListSource) ds.Tables[0]).GetList();
    }

    public void PopulateGrid(DataTable dt) {
        lstData.View = CreateGridViewColumns(dt);
        lstData.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
    }

    private GridView CreateGridViewColumns(DataTable dt) {
        // Create the GridView
        var gv = new GridView {AllowsColumnReorder = true};

        // Create the GridView Columns
        foreach (DataColumn item in dt.Columns) {
            var gvc = new GridViewColumn
                          {
                              DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(item.ColumnName),
                              Header = item.ColumnName,
                              Width = Double.NaN
                          };

            gv.Columns.Add(gvc);
        }

        return gv;
    }
```

also i have noticed that if I expand the last column to have the Horizontal Scroll bar show up, and it has a vertical bar, then the right side corners do show up.

Also if I manually define all the columns then again the rounded corners show up on all 4 sides (This is not ideal is I need the list view to be dynamic)